# Splunk Search query returns 'Unknown Search Command' error while trying to display search results using the Splunk Enterprise SDK for Java

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-sdk

I am trying to access Splunk results using java.
I have followed the below link to achieve the same
https://dev.splunk.com/enterprise/docs/devtools/java/sdk-java/howtousesdkjava/howtodisplaysearchsdkjava/

I am trying to give the below search String but getting the below exception

```
source="/u/application/xxxx/yyy/zzzz/logs/access_log" 
| eval server_type=mvindex(split('host', "."),0), site=mvindex(split('host', "."),1), country=mvindex(split('host', "."),2), domain=mvindex(split('host', "."),3), org=mvindex(split('host', "."),4) 
| search country="XX" serviceName="/services/*" 
| chart count by serviceName
```

Setting the Search String in job

```
String mySearch = "source=\"/u/applic/wsadmin/WMSE/apache/logs/httpd_60402/access_log\" | eval server_type=mvindex(split('host', \".\"),0), site=mvindex(split('host', \".\"),1), country=mvindex(split('host', \".\"),2), domain=mvindex(split('host', \".\"),3), org=mvindex(split('host', \".\"),4) |search country=\"us\" serviceName=\"/services/*\" | chart count by serviceName";
    Job job = service.getJobs().create(mySearch);
```

Exception in thread "main" com.splunk.HttpException: HTTP 400 -- Unknown search command 'source'

But the same code works with the below simple search command

```
String mySearch = "search * | head 5";
Job job = service.getJobs().create(mySearch);
```

Can someone help to understand the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding 'search' before the source should resolve it.
either 'search' or '|' should be the first command while creating search query via rest api.

Comment: Nkv, I tried adding search before source and tried. Now it gives me a different error

Exception in thread "main" com.splunk.HttpException: HTTP 403 -- You do not have permission to spawn real-time searches.

Comment: that  means user id didn't have permission to run real time search. Either you can add permission to run real time search or try to run oneshot Search as explained in the documentation shared in the original question.